# Migrating WordPress + WooCommerce from server to Local

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, migration, local-installation

I've been trying fora few day to migrate a WordPress/WooCommerce website from a server (OVH) to local. I've downloaded the latest version of my database from OVH and all the FTP through FileZilla.

I'm using MAMP to start the website locally. After following all the instruction from this tutorial : https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-local-server/ , when I start the website, it lands on an empty white page...

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Could be many things, debugging this can be difficult without deeper knowledge of setting up and managing servers. Are you sure the MAMP setup is correct (e.g. do other PHP files work)?

Comment: I have absolutely no knowledge of managing servers...

Comment: Then I suggest using something like [Local](https://localwp.com/) (there is another tool that I can't remember the name of ..), which is better suited for people oriented in simply setting it up locally without the troubles of server management.

Comment: Im guessing your .htaccess file doesn't contain the wordpress folder. make sure `RewriteBase /` is `RewriteBase /FOLDER_NAME/` AND `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` is `RewriteRule . /FOLDER_NAME/index.php [L]`

Comment: @Buttered_Toast you were right it doesn't contain the name of the folder but it's still not working.

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of your folder structure, also make sure the code of you wp-config.php is correct for your local project, also make sure your apache and mysql services are running

Comment: How can I attach a screenshot to a comment?